# How to implement javascript blocking modal dialog in with DHTML

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, modal-dialog

I have a website with a flash image viewer. Once user clicks on flash button, I need to give a confirmation modal dialog before saving the file and if user clicks on OK only I have to pop file download dialog.

Confirmation dialog with in flash is not an option for me. So I have to invoke JS function to pop a confirmation.

Within the site, a custom DHTML confirmation modal dialog is used and it has two JS callback functions one for "OK" and the other for "Cancel" button click event handers. I have to use this modal dialog for this need.

With Flash player 10 security features, it is unable to pop flash file download dialog via JavaScript.

Simple JS confirm dialog works for me as I can return the user's action by calling JS function from flash as JS confirm dialog is a blocking dialog.

How can I implement same blocking type custom confirm dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your popup into a `div`.
Make this `div` the top element in your page, eg: using `z-index`.
And give a fixed position with a height and width of 100%.
You can leave it transparent or give some effect using semi-transparent colors.

If you have `select` elements in your page, they will go through this `div`.
To avoid this problem, you can put behind the `div` a transparent `iframe` with the same size.